# LC circuit voltage

Tags: voltage, analog, passive-networks, tank

Suppose we have this LC circuit and assuming the capacitor is precharged with its voltage pointing to the left(left plate has an excess of negative charges and right plate has an excess of positive charges)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX77I8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is there an equation which will tell us the voltage between the 2 plates?Help appreciated

Comment: Yes, there are a pair of differential equations that can be used to solve this problem. Is this school work? If so, you need to show what you have tried.

Comment: It aint schoolwork i am asking because I am curious.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two differential equations that can be used to solve this circuit.

$$I = CV'$$

and

$$V = -LI'$$

The two equations can be combined to give

$$I = C(-LI')' = -LCI''$$

and

$$V = -L(CV')' = -LCV''$$

That is, the current and voltage both solve the same differential equation.

$$U = -LCU''$$

If you are familiar with differential equations, you will recognize that a sine wave with angular velocity \$\sqrt{LC}\$ will solve the equation.

for example,

$$V = A\sin(\sqrt{LC}t + \theta)$$

for any \$A\$ and \$\theta\$ will solve the differential equation. Knowing the initial conditions will allow one to solve for \$A\$ and \$\theta\$.